# how does logging_mixin in airflow source code work?

Tags: python, airflow

I was trying to practice reading source code, so I was reading airflow's source code.

Can somebody explain how logging_mixin.py ([github location](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/utils/log/logging_mixin.py)) works? I tried to use the module with my own class like this:

```
class Node(LoggingMixin):
"""Linked list node."""

...

def remove(self):
    self.log.info('remvoed')
```

But when I call remove on a node instance, nothing gets printed out.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I needed to set the logging configuration.